# java.net.BindException: адрес уже используется: JVM_Bind

Tags: java

Запускаю данный код в еклипсе, выводит ошибку

> Исключение в потоке «main» java.net.BindException: адрес уже используется: JVM_Bind

```
    public class Main {

       static ServerSocket ss;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
            ss = new ServerSocket(3128);
            while (true) {
                Socket s = ss.accept();
                System.err.println("Client accepted");
                new Thread(new SocketProcessor(s)).start();
            }
        }

        private static class SocketProcessor implements Runnable {

            private Socket s;
            private InputStream is;
            private OutputStream os;

            private SocketProcessor(Socket s) throws Throwable {
                this.s = s;
                this.is = s.getInputStream();
                this.os = s.getOutputStream();
            }

            public void run() {
                try {
                    readInputHeaders();
                    writeResponse("<html><body><h1>Hello from Habrahabr</h1></body></html>");
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    /*do nothing*/
                } finally {
                    try {
                        s.close();
                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                        /*do nothing*/
                    }
                }
                System.err.println("Client processing finished");
            }

            private void writeResponse(String s) throws Throwable {
                String response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
                        "Server: YarServer/2009-09-09\r\n" +
                        "Content-Type: text/html\r\n" +
                        "Content-Length: " + s.length() + "\r\n" +
                        "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
                String result = response + s;
                os.write(result.getBytes());
                os.flush();
            }

            private void readInputHeaders() throws Throwable {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                while(true) {
                    String s = br.readLine();
                    if(s == null || s.trim().length() == 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Указывает на данную строку

```
 ss = new ServerSocket(3128);
```

Comment: Какой-то другой процесс уже слушает порт 3128.

Comment: я туда разные порты указывал, ничего не менялось

Comment: Проверьте, какие порты у вас в системе уже заняты. `java.net.BindException` - это медицинский факт: порт занят, возьмите другой )

Comment: В документации на это исключения всего два варианта: занят порт или недопустимый адрес

Comment: Я этим занимался, большинство портов свободно, например 8081, но с ним так же не работает

Comment: Что делать в случае недопустимого адреса?